# Cycle inside PROJECTNAME_Tests; building could produce unreliable results

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, build, build-system

Before asking I was looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50709330/cycle-inside-building-could-produce-unreliable-results-xcode-10-error/50726360), I tried everything, but without success.

I'm trying to create a private cocoapods library, but keep getting this error.

```
Showing All Messages
Cycle inside Subscriptions_Tests; building could produce unreliable results.
Cycle details:
→ Target 'Subscriptions_Tests': CodeSign /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Subscriptions-dgxcyjrhborvtecmhutfjvyewrdg/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Subscriptions_Example.app
○ Target 'Subscriptions_Tests': CodeSign /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Subscriptions-dgxcyjrhborvtecmhutfjvyewrdg/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Subscriptions_Example.app
```

**What i've tried so far?**

- In `Build Phases` tried to move `Copy Bundle Resources` above all others -> No success ([This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50831437/1138498))
- Tried to update `CocoaPods`, remove `Derived Data` -> No success ([This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51541251/1138498))
- Tried to `Clean Build Folder` -> No success ([This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53364866/1138498))
- Tried to disable / re-enable `Enable Modules (C and Objective-C)` -> No success ([This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51513694/1138498))
- Tried [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64556134/xctest-running-tests-fails-with-cycle-inside-x-building-could-produce-unreliab), which seems that the user is facing pretty much the same issue, but i'm not using Carthage, so it's irrelevant.

Comment: Did anybody manage to fix this? I'm on Xcode 13.4 and I'm struggling with this